# Group unique records combined with list of values

Tags: xslt, utf-8, xslt-2.0

I am very new into working with XSLT and has an issue where we have to convert XML data into an XSL stylesheet.

I hope below makes sense:
I have 3 line of records where the area marked with yellow is the first part of the code and is the same values in all tags.

The values after this area is different per each value date.

I want to create a kind of grouping per unique set of the yellow marked data and then create a list of the different values in the "quote" section.

I have added and example of how I would like the end result to be.

I have no idea what to search for in the forum to get a hint to fix my issue - and is it possible to fix for a newbie as me?

Just want to mention that I have had help to create the mainpart of the code but I understand the code and I am able to make small adjustments to it.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wXvL.png)
[EndResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeCnc.png)

Code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Import>
      <Funds>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Record">
          <Fund>
            <xsl:attribute name="Id">
              <xsl:value-of select="./Fund_Id/text()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <FundData>
              <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="./FundData/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:for-each select="./*[not(name() = 'Fund_Id') and not(name() = 'FundData') and not(name() = 'NetAssetValue') and not(name() = 'Description')]">
                <xsl:variable name="attribute">
                  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$attribute}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:for-each>
             </FundData>
            <Quote>
              <xsl:attribute name="ValueDate2">
                <xsl:value-of select="./ValueDate/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Value/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </Quote>
          </Fund>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Funds>
     </Import>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Data I am using:

```
<Data>
<Record><Fund_Id>ABC</Fund_Id><FundData>Hello</FundData><ValueDate>2023-05-11</ValueDate><Percent>30.0181</Percent><ThemeId>9</ThemeId><Valuedate2>2023-05-09</Valuedate2><Value>149.84</Value></Record>
<Record><Fund_Id>ABC</Fund_Id><FundData>Hello</FundData><ValueDate>2023-05-11</ValueDate><Percent>30.0181</Percent><ThemeId>9</ThemeId><Valuedate2>2023-05-10</Valuedate2><Value>157.12</Value></Record>
<Record><Fund_Id>ABC</Fund_Id><FundData>Hello</FundData><ValueDate>2023-05-11</ValueDate><Percent>30.0181</Percent><ThemeId>9</ThemeId><Valuedate2>2023-05-11</Valuedate2><Value>136.07</Value></Record>
</Data>
```

The result I am looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
<Funds>
</Fund>
<Fund Id="ABC">
<FundData Name="Hello" ValueDate="2023-05-11" Percent="30.01810"ThemeId="9"/>
<Quote ValueDate="2023-05-09" Value="149.84"/>
<Quote ValueDate="2023-05-10" Value="157.12"/>
<Quote ValueDate="2023-05-11" Value="136.07"/>
</Fund>
</Funds>
</Import>
```

Comment: Please post your code **as code** within your question, not as picture in external link. Add also  your attempted XSLT stylesheet and the expected result - see: [mcve].

Comment: Also grouping here is an FAQ, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. And note that you explicitly tagged the question for XSLT 1.0 while posting an image of an XSLT version 2.0 stylesheet.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, which tool is used in that screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wXvL.png?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I was focused on xml 1.0 but I have changed the tag now and added the code.

Regarding the tool I am working in an internal system that has a functionality to build and test stylesheets. The system has some standard xml formats (the data I am using) and can only build tags but  I need attributes so I am trying to convert data buy this code.

Comment: /I am very new into working with XLST/ Funny how people always spell it that way until they get used to it!

Comment: @MichaelKay haha, just noticed my typo on XLST - fat fingers with difficulties in learning to type S before L :)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clean up your code a bit to make it easier to read. You can replace this:

```
        <Fund>
            <xsl:attribute name="Id">
              <xsl:value-of select="./Fund_Id/text()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <FundData>
              <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="./FundData/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:for-each select="./*[not(name() = 'Fund_Id') and not(name() = 'FundData') and not(name() = 'NetAssetValue') and not(name() = 'Description')]">
                <xsl:variable name="attribute">
                  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="{$attribute}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:for-each>
             </FundData>
            <Quote>
              <xsl:attribute name="ValueDate2">
                <xsl:value-of select="./ValueDate/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                <xsl:value-of select="./Value/text()" />
              </xsl:attribute>
            </Quote>
          </Fund>
```

by this:

```
   <Fund Id="{Fund_Id}">
     <FundData Name={FundData}"
       <xsl:for-each select="* except (FundData|NetAssetValue|Description)">
         <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </FundData>
     <Quote ValueDate2="{ValueDate}" Value="{Value}"/>
   </Fund>
```

Now that the code is more readable it's clear that you are creating one `FundData` and one `Quote` for each input `Record`, whereas you want to group the records based on common attribute values; so in XSLT 2.0+ you want `xsl:for-each-group`. In fact you want it with a composite grouping key, which is an XSLT 3.0 capability, but if your processor supports XSLT 2.0 then there is a very good chance that it supports XSLT 3.0, so the grouping would be

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" 
         group-by="Fund_Id, FundData, ValueDate, Percent, ThemeId"
         composite="yes">
```

But if you really do need pure XSLT 2.0 then you can construct a simple key using string concatenation as suggested by @MartinHonnen.

Comment: Loved you in "Wonderful Copenhagen".

Comment: Thanks a lot - also for the cleanup - I will definitly add it to the code.
And test the group function both as XSLT 3.0 and 2.0.

I really appreciate your assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

To group the records by the combined value of `Fund_Id`, `FundData`, `ValueDate`, `Percent` and `ThemeId` you can do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <Import>
        <Funds>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="string-join((Fund_Id, FundData, ValueDate, Percent, ThemeId), '|')">
                <Fund Id="{Fund_Id}">
                    <FundData Name="{FundData}" ValueDate="{ValueDate}" Percent="{Percent}" ThemeId="(ThemeId)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Quote ValueDate="{Valuedate2}" Value="{Value}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Fund>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Funds>
    </Import>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result when applied to your input example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
   <Funds>
      <Fund Id="ABC">
         <FundData Name="Hello"
                   ValueDate="2023-05-11"
                   Percent="30.0181"
                   ThemeId="(ThemeId)"/>
         <Quote ValueDate="2023-05-09" Value="149.84"/>
         <Quote ValueDate="2023-05-10" Value="157.12"/>
         <Quote ValueDate="2023-05-11" Value="136.07"/>
      </Fund>
   </Funds>
</Import>
```

is slightly different than the result you show - but then the result you show is not a well-formed XML document.

---

Note that in XSLT 3.0 you could simplify:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="string-join((Fund_Id, FundData, ValueDate, Percent, ThemeId), '|')">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="Fund_Id, FundData, ValueDate, Percent, ThemeId" composite="yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up my code and testet XSLT 3.0 grouping without any luck.
But by combining your answers I have been able to create a code that gives me the wanted result.

I only group by Fund_ID and Valuedate as they are the key for when the record is unique - hope it makes sense (it does in my head).

I hope my comment does not get deleted even though I write I am very thankful for your assistance.

The code I will be using is this

```
xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <FundImport>
     <Funds>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="string-join((Fund_Id, ValueDate), '|')">
                <Fund Id="{Fund_Id}">
             <FundData Name="{FundData}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="* except (Fund_Id|FundData|NetAssetValue|ValueDate2)">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:attribute name="Description">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="./Description/text() = 'false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="''" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Description/text()" />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:attribute>          
            </FundData>
                        
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Quote ValueDate="{Valuedate2}" NetAssetValue="{NetAssetValue}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Fund>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Funds>
 </FundImport>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```